# How to use promise with set interval

Tags: javascript, angular, api, real-time, setinterval

I’m trying to solve a simple problem here but I have no idea what direction to take.

```
getAuthNumber() // returns a promise with a number (eg 98765)
// response times can be 5s-20s

<div class=“auth”> </div>


//code 
let counter = 0;
let el = document.getElementsbyClassName(“auth”)[0];

let func = setInterval(function(){
   counter++;
   getAuthNumber().then((num)=>{
         return [num, counter];

    }).then(res){
          If(counter == res[1])
                el.innerHTML = res[0];
}, 10000);
```

I need to write a function that gets the auth number every 10s & displays it in the block below. I’ve tried using set interval but getAuthNumber() can take more than 10s to return in which case, I need to discard that response and only show the current value.

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jakearchibald/cb03f15670817001b1157e62a076fe95) by Jake Archibald (see [JavaScript counters the hard way - HTTP 203](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU)) into the following code:

```
function promiseInterval(milliseconds, signal, promiseFactory, callback) {
  const start = performance.now();

  function tick(time) {
    if (signal.aborted){
       return;
    }

    promiseFactory().then(
        value => {
            callback(value);
            scheduleTick(time);
        }
    );
  }

  function scheduleTick(time) {
    const elapsed = time - start;
    const roundedElapsed = Math.round(elapsed / milliseconds) * milliseconds;
    const targetNext = start + roundedElapsed + milliseconds;
    const delay = targetNext - performance.now();
    setTimeout(tick, delay);
  }

  scheduleTick(start);
}
```

Starting from the gist, I have removed the use of `requestAnimationFrame` and `document.timeline.currentTime` (using only `performance.now`), and I have added the `promiseFactory` parameter, plus some renaming (`animationInterval` renamed to `promiseInterval`, `ms` renamed to `milliseconds` and `scheduleFrame` renamed to `scheduleTick`) and formatting.

You would use it like this:

```
const controller = new AbortController(); // This is used to stop

promiseInterval(
    10000,                       // 10s
    controller.signal,           // signal, to stop the process call `controller.abort`
    getAuthNumber,               // the promise factory
    num => {el.innerHTML = num;} // this is what you do with the values
);
```

---

It will not really call `getAuthNumber` each 10 seconds. Instead, it will wait until `getAuthNumber` completes and schedule to call on the next 10 seconds interval, and repeat. So it is not calling it multiple times and discarding values.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use setInterval instead use setTimeOut function.
setInterval execution depends on the CPU usage, if it in case increased the setinterval will not gets completed in the interval specified

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is run an `async` function inside `setInterval`. In the following code snippet, the `getAuth` function completes after 2s but `setInterval` runs every 1s. But it still works because there is an `async` funciton inside `setInterval`.

```js
const getAuth = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(Math.random()), 2000);
  });
};

const setDiv = async () => {
  const res = await getAuth();
  console.log(res);
};

setInterval(setDiv, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But If the response time is variable, i.e we want to show iff the response comes before the next request is made, since the previous data is stale.
Ex. 1st sec -> promise1 -> 234 -  takes 1 sec -> show
2nd sec -> promise2 -> 743 -  takes 3 sec to come back -> dont show
3rd sec -> promise3 -> 643-  takes <1sec ->  show